# How to plot a graph by reading the data from text file

Tags: graphs, sharelatex

I want to read the data from text file and plot a XY graph. But, the Problem in my text file is I do not have data in any columns. It is some thing like which you can see in the screenshot attached. For every second there are different values for each Parameter. So, the entire file is about 6629 seconds. I want to plot the graph between any chosen 2 Parameters , for e.g. `Vehicle Speed` and `CO2masswet`. I tried googling but could not find anything. Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Well, it could certainly be done within LaTeX, but if you're familiar with any programming languages such as Python, it would probably be easier to parse the file using that first, to generate a text file containing columnar data.

Comment: I am not familiar with any of the programming languages. can you share me a example how can I do that

Comment: LaTeX or Python? Either way, wont have time to do that right now (to be honest, not even sure I would be able to do it with LaTeX, at least not easily), maybe later.

Comment: I want to do in latex

Comment: Maybe the software that generated the data text file in the first place has different export formats such as CSV?!

Comment: You could create a two column table using pgfplottable with = as a column separator, Then create comma delimited strings for each variable by copying the entries one element at a time. I'm not sure what will happen with the "===" lines, but it should be distinctive.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you asked for, but some might find it of interest. (You've tagged your question with [sharelatex](/questions/tagged/sharelatex), and I'm not sure if it possible to use this solution on ShareLaTeX. It is however definitely possible on Overleaf, see example on https://www.overleaf.com/read/byrgzftndfmq It requires the use of a custom `latexmkrc` file, which I got from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-pythontex-on-overleaf/qfjttkyfdtyt)

Parsing a file like that is very easy with Python. I'm sure it can be done with e.g. Lua, so a solution using LuaTeX would be possible. I wouldn't be surprised it if can be done with pure (La)TeX as well.

However, I'm much more comfortable with Python, so the code below uses the `pythontex` package to achieve this. Having Python installed is also a requirement, of course.

I made a sample data file called `mydata.dat` that looks as follows:

```
================================
======== Time = 0Sec ==========
Distance = 0
speed = 0
temperature = 0
================================
======== Time = 2Sec ==========
Distance = 1
speed = 2
temperature = 0.1
================================
======== Time = 4Sec ==========
Distance = 3
speed = 5
temperature = 0.3
```

As far as I can see this matches the format of your data file, though I do not know what happens between timesteps. I assumed that the only delimiter between timesteps is the line of all `=`.

Because this uses `pythontex`, there is an extra compilation step required. I.e., you need to run

```
pdflatex test
pythontex test
pdflatex test
```

where your `.tex` file is called `test.tex`. The output of the code below is

[image]

So what I do is first read the whole data file into a dictionary called `data`. I then define a Python function that prints out `\addplot coordinates {(x1,y1)(x2,y2)...};`, with the coordinates based on the data.
I use this function inside an `axis` environment from `pgfplots`, as `\py|printplot('xvar','yvar')|`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.14,
  width=6cm,
  height=5cm
}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
with open('mydata.dat') as dd:
    for line in dd:
        if line.startswith('='):
            if 'Time' in line:
                data['Time'] += [line.split()[3][:-3]]
        else:
            key, _, val = line.split()
            data[key] += [val]

def printplot(key1,key2,plotargs=None):
    coords = ''.join(['({0},{1})'.format(x,y)
        for x,y in zip(data[key1],data[key2])])
    if plotargs is None:
        plot = r'\addplot coordinates {' + coords + '};'
    else:
        plot = r'\addplot' + plotargs + ' coordinates {' + coords + '};'

    print(plot)        

\end{pycode}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=Distance,
  ylabel=Speed,
  title={Speed vs.\@ distance},
  ]
\py|printplot('Distance','speed')|
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=Time,
  ylabel=Temperature,
  title={Temperature vs.\@ time}
  ]
\py|printplot('Time','temperature',plotargs='+[red,thick,mark=x]')|
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```